# Why Doesn't the Command Line Argument Work When Put Directly Into a Command in a Script?

Tags: powershell

I am struggling to understand why using $args[$i] directly in this command doesn't work. It gives a completely wrong answer.

```
$memory=$(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "$($args[$i])"}  | select -expand VirtualMemorySize64)
```

However, putting the command line argument into another variable and using that one works.

```
$id=($args[$i])
$memory=$(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "$id"}  | select -expand VirtualMemorySize64)
```

An explanation on why this is would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Every [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) in PowerShell has its own copy of the automatic `$args` array** in which positionally passed arguments are automatically collected.

Therefore, `$args` inside `{$_.id -eq "$($args[$i])"}` is *not* the same as `$args` at the script level, so you indeed need to save the script-level value in an auxiliary variable first, as in your 2nd snippet, which can be streamlined as follows:

```
# Must use aux. variable to access the script-level $args inside
# the Where-Object script block.
$id = $args[$i] 

$memory = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.id -eq $id } | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty VirtualMemorySize64
```

Note the absence of superfluous `(...)` and `$(...)`, and the removal of quoting around `"$id"`, given that the `.Id` property of process object is a *number* (type `[int]`).

Taking a step back, I suggest *declaring parameters* in your script, which is preferable to using `$args` - the variables holding the values of such parameters can be used without a problem in `Where-Object` script blocks.

---

Generally:

- It is only meaningful to access `$args` inside a script block that you've invoked *with arguments*, which is not the case in a script block passed to [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object), where the input to the script block comes (only) from the *pipeline*, via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables)
- By contrast, you *can* pass arguments to a script block, if you invoke it with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), for instance:  `& { "[$args]" } 'foo'` yields `[foo]`.